# Escrever um struct em um endereço/ponteiro

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, struct, winapi

Eu aloco memória usando a função `VirtualAlloc()` e ela retorna um ponteiro `ptrAlloc`. Eu gostaria criar um objeto nesse endereço, algo parecido com isso:

```cpp
void* ptrAlloc = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof strTeste, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

// Quero fazer isso sem criar no stack primeiro
strTeste testeConsole;  // Isso
*(strTeste*)ptrAlloc = testeConsole;
```

"*strTeste*" é o nome da estrutura como demonstração, e como escrito no comentario, não gosto do exemplo pois ele cria no stack pra depois copiar para a memória alocada.
Assim, já que eu tenho um ponteiro para um endereço de memória, como eu posso criar um objeto nesse endereço?

exemplo 2:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

struct strTeste
{
   //coisas
   char i;
};

int main()
{
    void* ptrAlloc = VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof strTeste, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    // Quero fazer isso sem criar no stack primeiro
    strTeste testeConsole;  // Isso
    *(strTeste*)ptrAlloc = testeConsole;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2:

A principal razão dessa pergunta é a de "criar um objeto nessa nova memória", pelos motivos de que:

exemplo 3:

```
struct strTeste
{
    int a;
    int b = 1;
};

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR pCmdLine,
                    int nCmdShow)
{
    // Edit 3, comentários

    strTeste Teste;    // Não quero fazer isso
    // Quero alocar na memória e criar um objeto nela, como no exemplo
    strTeste* ptrTeste = (strTeste*)VirtualAlloc(0, sizeof strTeste, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    
    int var1 = Teste.b;      // resultado de var1 é 1, pois isso está escrito na estrutura.
    int var2 = ptrTeste->b;  // mas aqui o resultado de var2 é 0, pois VirtualAlloc() zera a região alocada e só estamos interpretando essa memória como a estrutura, o cast do void*

    return 0;
}
```

Com esse exemplo, `var1` vai ter terminar como `1` que é o valor esperado, já que na estrutura está assim. Mas em `var2` vai terminar com `0`, porque `VirtualAlloc()` zera a memória.

Eu gostaria de obter o resultado de `var1` com a memória alocada sem ter que copiar, como demonstrado no primeiro exemplo.

Comment: poste algo que se possa compilar, um exemplo mínimo com headers e tudo...

Comment: @arfneto mas aonde isso é importante? Eu só quero criar um objeto em um endereço. Se faz tanta diferença eu vou colocar isso dentro de `int main()` e pronto.

Comment: @arfneto pronto, mas como eu disse, não faz diferença

Comment: A diferença seria de alguém querer compilar isso pra te ajudar e não precisar preencher nada para ter algo compilável. É o sentido de _exemplo minimamente compilável_. Que é `CMD` em seu programa?

Comment: tá "CMD" foi um erro ao copiar, esse é o nome da classe original.

Comment: mas para o caso que vc falou "alguém querer compilar isso", não precisa, esse código está certo, mas gostaria de ser realizado de outra maneira, como escrito na pergunta.

Comment: Não é pela necessidade. É uma conveniência, uma gentileza nesse caso. Eu usei o código que postou e agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi o que quer fazer. Mas `VirtualAlloc()` do modo como está usando já vai alocar aquela área. E vai precisar de um ponteiro para ela para poder chamar a função e pode usar apenas esse.

Imagino que tenha lido a documentação em [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) ou outro lugar.

#### EXEMPLO

```
#define K_ 1024
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char buf[7 * K_];
} Area;

int main(void)
{
    SYSTEM_INFO info;
    GetSystemInfo(&info);
    printf(
        "PageSize: %d bytes. Area a alocar: %llu\n",
        info.dwPageSize, sizeof(Area));

    const DWORD al_type = MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT;

    // tenta alocar 7K
    Area* area = (Area*) VirtualAlloc(
        NULL, sizeof(area), al_type, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (area == NULL)
    {
        printf("VirtualAlloc() falhou!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(
        "VirtualAlloc() OK: %llu bytes alocados!\n",
        sizeof(area));

    // tera alocado um multiplo de pagesize?
    size_t page = 0;
    if (sizeof(Area) % info.dwPageSize == 0)
        page = sizeof(area);
    else
        page = (1 + sizeof(area) / info.dwPageSize) * info.dwPageSize;
    printf(
        "VirtualAlloc() pode alocar %llu paginas\n",
        page / info.dwPageSize);

    const uint8_t  val   = 0x42;
    const size_t   final = page - 1;  // 8k = 2 paginas
    *((unsigned char*)area + final)         = val;
    printf(
        "final da pagina = %x (esperado %x)\n",
        *((unsigned char*)area + final), val);

    int res = VirtualFree( (void*)area, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    if (res == 0)
    {
        printf("VirtualFree() falhou!\n");
        return -2;
    }
    printf("VirtualFree() OK!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Esse programa aloca espaço para a estrutura. Note que a estrutura tem `7K` mas a página na máquina que estou usando tem `4K` e assim `VirtualAlloc()` deve alocar 2 páginas. Então o programa tenta gravar no final do que seria a área de 2 páginas para ver se consegue. E depois chama `VirtualFree()` para liberar o espaço.

#### Sáida do exemplo

```
PageSize: 4096 bytes. Area a alocar: 7168
VirtualAlloc() OK: 8 bytes alocados!
VirtualAlloc() pode alocar 1 paginas
final da pagina = 42 (esperado 42)
VirtualFree() OK!
```

Comment: (Primeiro que o "down vote não foi meu") Tudo bem, vc aloca e teste o tamanho alocado para a estrutura. Entretanto vc não criou um objeto na memória alocada. (Eu vou atualizar a pergunta) Mas, mesmo que eu não esteja usando no momento, se eu só usar um ponteiro eu não tenho como usar construtores. Ou para um exemplo mais perto de C e mais perto do caso atual, se eu tenho variáveis que já possuem um valor dentro da estrutura, se eu só apontar para a nova memória eles não vão estar com esses valores.

Comment: Espero que o novo edit ajude a entender a pergunta.

Comment: Não foi eu quem votou, mas está errado isso. Primeiro que está marcado c e c++ na pergunta implicando duas respostas diferentes. Se for c, c não tem suporte nativo a instanciação de objetos então a pergunta se torna *como implementar o paradigma POO em C* cujo a resposta é muito longa. Se for C++ a resposta é *use o operador `new` que instancia dinamicamente um objeto e o aloca no heap*

Comment: @AugustoVasques a questão gira em torno de `VirtualAlloc()` de `memoryapi.h` e envolve `C` e `C++`  mas não `new`. Veja o código apresentado pelo autor.

Comment: @EnderMega depois vou deixar outro exemplo considerando seu novo comentário. Espero que ajude. E espero estar entendendo :)

Comment: Ele quer instanciar em C uma struct tal qual C++.

Comment: @AugustoVasques de todo modo trata-se do uso de `VirtualAlloc` de `memoryapi.h` que pode ser chamada igualmente de `C` e `C++` e de uma série de linguagens. É a API do Windows. Vou postar um exemplo em `C++` já que só tem essas linguagens listadas.

Comment: Eu estou na rua e mais tarde dou feedbak.

Comment: Concordo com seu argumento. Você está respondendo fielmente ao que foi perguntado. Segura ai.

Comment: @AugustoVasques acrescentei 2 exemplos em `C++` mas ainda não estou certo de que sejam solução :)

Comment: Cabe ao AP fazer esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 0):

#### Criando um  objeto na memória alocada

> **Da questão:** *Entretanto vc não criou um objeto na memória alocada. (Eu vou atualizar a pergunta) Mas, mesmo que eu não esteja usando no momento, se eu só usar um ponteiro eu não tenho como usar construtores. Ou para um exemplo mais perto de C e mais perto do caso atual, se eu tenho variáveis que já possuem um valor dentro da estrutura, se eu só apontar para a nova memória eles não vão estar com esses valores**

Usar `C` ou `C++` --- ou Python ou qualquer outra linguagem que possa acessar a API --- não vai fazer diferença nesse caso. `VirtualAlloc()` tem a ver com VBS Virtualization-based security e talvez possa ver mais sobre isso na [documentaçao](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2018/06/05/virtualization-based-security-vbs-memory-enclaves-data-protection-through-isolation/#:%7E:text=An%20enclave%20is%20an%20isolated%20region%20of%20memory,by%20Virtual%20Trust%20Levels%2C%20VTL0%20and%20VT1%2C%20respectively).

Não pode criar valores numa estrutura que ainda não exista. E se ela já existir e criar outra em um `memory enclave` ou no `heap` vai ter que copiar os dados. `VirtualAlloc()` é como `new` ou `calloc()` exceto pelo lado VBS.

E copiar faz pouco sentido porque isso só existe para proteção. O hypervisor do Windows controla totalmente o acesso a essa área. Mas se os dados já estavam antes na área de usuário do processo só faria sentido se precisasse fazer algum processamento confidencial **depois** de copiar para a área segura. E aí não teria feito essa pergunta aqui no SO.

#### Do que eu escrevi:

```
    Area* area = (Area*) VirtualAlloc( 
        NULL, sizeof(area),
        al_type, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

#### Do seu exemplo 2:

```
    strTeste Teste;
    strTeste* ptrTeste = (strTeste*)VirtualAlloc(
        0, 
        sizeof strTeste,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE);

    int var1 = Teste.b;
    int var2 = ptrTeste->b;
```

Se já alocou estaticamente `Teste` vai ter que copiar para a área segura. Mas porque fez isso? Não pode simplesmente gravar lá **depois**? `Teste.b` é um `int` e `ptrTeste->b` é outro, em endereços diferentes e em locais diferentes. E lembro que `VirtualAlloc()` aloca em páginas e não em bytes. Veja a documentação e o programa de exemplo que eu deixei.
Porque escrever como a seguir não está bem? Talvez sua necessidade não tenha ficado clara para mim.

```
    strTeste* ptrTeste = (strTeste*)VirtualAlloc(0,
        sizeof strTeste,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    int var2 = ptrTeste->b;
```

#### Da questão:

> **Da Questão:** *Mas, mesmo que eu não esteja usando no momento, se eu só usar um ponteiro eu não tenho como usar construtores*

Não sei se entendi o que seria. Se pensa em escrever isso em `C++` não faria diferença. Isso está em `memoryapi.h` afinal. É Windows. E `C`.

### De todo modo vou deixar um exemplo em `C++`.

### um outro exemplo, desta vez em `C++` usando a mesma `VirtualAlloc()`

```
struct Area
{
    size_t   size;
    uint8_t* buffer;
    Area();  // 1 pagina
    Area(size_t, uint8_t const = 0);  // + valor
    ~Area();
};
```

Essa classe tem um buffer simples, `unsigned char` e no exemplo vai ser criada em um `memory enclave`. O construtor padrão cria uma área de 1 página, pegando o tamanho via `GetSystemInfo()`, claro. O segundo aceita o número de páginas e opcionalmente um valor para preencher o buffer todo. Lembro que `VirtualAlloc()` sempre preenche com `0`. Na saída a área é liberada via `VirtualFree()`.

**A diferença para uma alocação comum está no fato dessa área ser segura e estar controlada pelo hypervisor do Windows.**

#### Codigo em C++

É o mesmo programa que o anterior em C, apenas trocando os `printf()` por `format` e colocando o código nos construtores e destrutor.

#### `main() para esse teste

```
int main(void)
{
    {
        Area teste(4, 0x42);
        cout << format(
            "main(): Area tem {:>8} bytes alocados. Ultimo "
            "byte = 0x{:0x} [Esperado: 0x42]\n",
            teste.size, *(teste.buffer + teste.size - 1));
    }
    Area outra;
    cout << format(
        "main(): Area tem {:>8} bytes alocados. Ultimo "
        "byte = 0x{:0x} [Esperado: 0x00]\n",
        outra.size, *(outra.buffer + outra.size - 1));
    return 0;
}
```

É algo simples:

- ao declarar `Area teste(4, 0x42)` vai criar 16k em um buffer interno de `unsigned char`. O `cout` mostra o último byte, que deve ter esse valor.
- ao declarar `Area outra` vai usar o construtorpadrão e o comportamento padrão de `VirtualAlloc()` e alocar uma página preenchida com `0`.
- ao final do escopo a área é liberada via `VirtualFree()`.

#### saída deste exemplo

```
PageSize: ****4096 bytes. Area a alocar: ***16384 bytes
VirtualAlloc() OK: ***16384 bytes alocados!
main(): Area tem    16384 bytes alocados. Ultimo byte = 0x42 [Esperado: 0x42]
VirtualFree(16384) OK!

PageSize: ****4096 bytes. Area a alocar: ****4096 bytes
VirtualAlloc() OK: ****4096 bytes alocados!
main(): Area tem     4096 bytes alocados. Ultimo byte = 0x0 [Esperado: 0x00]
VirtualFree(4096) OK!
```

#### O código em um arquivo `C++`

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <format>
#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::format;

struct Area
{
    size_t   size;
    uint8_t* buffer;
    Area();  // 1 pagina
    Area(size_t, uint8_t const = 0);  // + valor
    ~Area();
};

int main(void)
{
    {
        Area teste(4, 0x42);
        cout << format(
            "main(): Area tem {:>8} bytes alocados. Ultimo "
            "byte = 0x{:0x} [Esperado: 0x42]\n",
            teste.size, *(teste.buffer + teste.size - 1));
    }
    Area outra;
    cout << format(
        "main(): Area tem {:>8} bytes alocados. Ultimo "
        "byte = 0x{:0x} [Esperado: 0x00]\n",
        outra.size, *(outra.buffer + outra.size - 1));
    return 0;
}

Area::Area() : Area(1, 0){};

Area::Area(size_t pages, uint8_t valor)
{
    SYSTEM_INFO info;
    GetSystemInfo(&info);
    size = pages * info.dwPageSize;
    std::cerr << format(
        "PageSize: {:*>8} bytes. Area a alocar: {:*>8} "
        "bytes\n",
        info.dwPageSize, size);

    const DWORD al_type = MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT;

    buffer = (uint8_t*)VirtualAlloc(
        NULL, size, al_type, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (buffer == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "VirtualAlloc() falhou!\n";
        size = 0;
        return;
    }
    std::cerr << format(
        "VirtualAlloc() OK: {:*>8} bytes alocados!\n",
        size);
    memset(buffer, valor, size);
}

Area::~Area()
{
    if (buffer == NULL) return;
    auto res = VirtualFree((void*)buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    if (res == 0)
        cerr << "VirtualFree() falhou!\n\n";
    else
        cerr << format("VirtualFree({}) OK!\n\n",size);
};
```

#### outro exemplo em `C++`

Este é o mesmo que o anterior, mas com `printf()` caso se use um compilador antigo que não aceite `format` ainda.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;

struct Area
{
    size_t   size;
    uint8_t* buffer;
    Area();  // 1 pagina
    Area(size_t, uint8_t const = 0);  // + valor
    ~Area();
};

int main(void)
{
    {
        Area teste(4, 0x42);
        printf(
            "main(): Area tem %llu bytes alocados. Ultimo "
            "byte = 0x%x [Esperado: 0x42]\n",
            teste.size, *(teste.buffer + teste.size - 1));
    }
    Area outra;
    printf(
        "main(): Area tem %llu bytes alocados. Ultimo "
        "byte = 0x%x [Esperado: 0x00]\n",
        outra.size, *(outra.buffer + outra.size - 1));
    return 0;
}

Area::Area() : Area(1, 0){};

Area::Area(size_t pages, uint8_t valor)
{
    SYSTEM_INFO info;
    GetSystemInfo(&info);
    size = pages * info.dwPageSize;
    printf(
        "PageSize: %d bytes. Area a alocar: %llu"
        "bytes\n",
        info.dwPageSize, size);

    const DWORD al_type = MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT;

    buffer = (uint8_t*)VirtualAlloc(
        NULL, size, al_type, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (buffer == nullptr)
    {
        printf("VirtualAlloc() falhou!\n");
        size = 0;
        return;
    }
    printf(
        "VirtualAlloc() OK: %llu bytes alocados!\n", size);
    memset(buffer, valor, size);
}

Area::~Area()
{
    if (buffer == NULL) return;
    auto res = VirtualFree((void*)buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    if (res == 0)
        printf("VirtualFree() falhou!\n\n");
    else
        printf("VirtualFree(%llu) OK!\n\n", size);
};
```

A saída é claro a mesma.

Comment: "Se já alocou estaticamente Teste vai ter que copiar para a área segura. Mas porque fez isso? Não pode simplesmente gravar lá depois?"
Então, o que acontece é que na estrutura "Teste.b" inicialmente vai ter um resultado diferente de "ptrTeste->b", pois em "Teste.b" um objeto foi criado e o valor inicializado, já em "ptrTeste->b" estamos interpretando uma nova memória como a estrutura `strTeste` obtendo um resultado diferente do esperado.

Comment: O exemplo em `C++` está mais perto do que precisa ou de nada serviu? Não pode já construir o valor inicial na área nova? Entende que esse é o objetivo do tal _memory enclave_?